# How to retrieve binary data via HTTP in Angular?

Tags: angular, http, blob

I am writing an Angular/TypeScript app in Cordova that needs to download a binary file from a server.

Based upon [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43163684/how-angular2-http-request-can-return-body-as-binary), I could find out that I need to set an appropriate response type on the request parameters to prevent Angular from attempting to interpret the response body as JSON (which would lead to a crash, as it's binary data).

Answers in that question and the [docs](https://angular.io/api/http/ResponseContentType) point me to `Blob` and `ArrayBuffer` as likely values.

Unfortunately, I cannot find any explanation on what is the difference between these two (no, [the respective question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821096/what-is-the-difference-between-an-arraybuffer-and-a-blob) has not really enlightened me), and both fail in their own ways.

**ArrayBuffer**

When using this, my app crashes with a `RangeError` due to exceeding some maximum stack size deep down in the internals of Angular<sup>1</sup>.

**Blob**

With this, the request goes through, but unless I'm missing something, the debugger shows that I am only getting a small object withe blob size and the MIME type, but the actual binary data is missing!

What's more, the [answer on the aforementioned question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43164489/1430156) points out a `TextDecoder` to "decode the result".

**Can't I just get the binary response body as a byte array somehow?**

---

<sup>1</sup>: That I actually have to extend this app that was started by another (more or less inaccessible to me) team, whose members added several layers of wrapping and parameter/result transformation around Angular's `Http` service does not make things easier to debug, but I am pretty confident I have set my breakpoints at the bottommost level and am thus not experiencing any effects of the wrappers.

Comment: Does "small object" means the `size` property of the `Blob` object is smaller than expected?

Comment: @cshu: No, the size property is exactly the expected value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access blob as byte array, use FileReader:

```
//use slice if your blob is too big
var chunkBlob = blobObject.slice(offset, chunk_size);

var fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.onload = function() {
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(this.result);
}
fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(chunkBlob);
```

As for the difference between Blob and ArrayBuffer, there isn't much you can do to a blob object. In contrast, ArrayBuffer can be accessed synchronously via `DataView`, `TypedArray`, or `TextDecoder`. ArrayBuffer is part of ECMAScript, but Blob is not.

[From mozilla.org:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob)

> A Blob object represents a file-like object of immutable, raw data.
>   Blobs represent data that isn't necessarily in a JavaScript-native
>   format.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Where does `slice` in the first line come from? Are you saying the data is actually in the object, but hidden from the debugger, so I have to extract it by means of some `slice` method?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper `slice` on blob works in a similar way as string. It just returns a smaller partial blob. Usually that first line should be unnecessary. I just worry about the size of blob might be too big.

Comment: Once I realized I had to capture the `onloadend` event, I could wrap this process into a promise that returns the `Uint8Array` in the end, so it works now. Thank you!