# Angular POST returns 500 error from ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, http, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm posting `data` from Angular client to ASP.NET Core Web API. In case when `data` has latin europe chars like ć,č,š it returns 500 Internal error, otherwise it return 201.

This is `data` class:

```
export class FinalFormData {
    name: string;
    url: string;
    dateCreated: Date;
    tags: any[];
}
```

Function for handling data for POST function:

```
this.data.postData(this.finalData)
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.finalData = data;
        this.router.navigate(["/"]);
    }, err => console.log(err));
```

Function for posting data:

```
public postData(data: FinalFormData): Observable<FinalFormData> {
    return this.http.post<FinalFormData>("/api/links", data, {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        })
    });
}
```

Web API

```
    [HttpPost("")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]FinalFormViewModel theLink)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var newLink = new Links
            {
                UserName = User.Identity.Name,
                Url = theLink.Url,
                Name = theLink.Name,
                DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow
            };
            //newLink.Name = _repository.GetTitle(newLink.Url);

            _repository.AddLink(newLink);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            Links link = _repository.GetLinkByName(newLink.Name);

            foreach (var tag in theLink.Tags)
            {
                var newTag = new Tags
                {
                    Name = tag
                };
                _repository.AddTag(link, newTag, newLink.UserName);
            }

            // Returning data

            var data = new FinalFormViewModel()
            {
                Name = newLink.Name,
                Url = newLink.Url,
                DateCreated = newLink.DateCreated,
                Tags = newLink.Tags.Select(t => t.Name).ToList()
            };
            if (await _repository.SaveChangesAsync())
            {
                return Created($"api/links/{theLink.Name}", data);
            }             
        }
        return BadRequest("Failed to save the link");
    }
```

When debugging in Web API in every case code reach `return Created($"api/links/{theLink.Name}", data);` which means it returns 201 status.

But in case when those chars like č,ć,ž are part of `url` string even though it returs 201, in browser I get the error in console with message:

```
"Http failure response for http://localhost:54105/api/links: 500 Internal Server Error"
```

After this subscribing to an Observable won't reach success block. In other cases without those special chars it works fine.

Network response:

[image: network response]

**EDIT**

I actually now find the server error:

```
InvalidOperationException: Invalid non-ASCII or control character in header: 0x0161

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.FrameHeaders.ThrowInvalidHeaderCharacter(char ch)
```

Comment: Use a Browser and go to the webpage and check the contents type. You are using : 'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.  The webpage is using a different type of encoding.

Comment: @jdweng I posted picture above.

Comment: Your error might be in *return Created($"api/links/{theLink.Name}", data);*. Are you sure *{theLink.Name}* has value?

Comment: I want to see headers with the web response not with http request/response.  It looks like you are using http 1.1 which is giving Chunked mode.  You may need to set to http 1.0 which is stream mode.  The 201 response is due to chunk mode and you will need to send a next chunk message otherwise you will timeout.  Never found a way to send next chunk use a httprequest.

Comment: @IgorDimchevski your hint actually gave me solution. `theLink.Name` has value, but instead I had to use `theLink.Url` which doesn't contains non-ASCII chars. Now works fine.

Comment: I am happy to hear that @gagro

Comment: hey @gagro could you mark someone as answer this way people browsing know this has been solved and can benefit from what you've learned? thank you. :)

Comment: @tatsu If you read carefully you can see that none of those **answers** gave me solution. IgorDimchevski's **comment** gave me hint for solution and I voted for comment.

Comment: actually I did read and that's why I decided to include IgorDimchevski fix in my answer (check the edit dates). Think of the people other than you browsing this site.noone browses the comments of all the answers + the question when looking for an urgent fix. If you really feel my other info is more detrimental then helpful I'll remove it and leave only IgorDimchevski so you can mark me or someone as answer. Marking an answer is paramount to how stackoverflow functions because when you query a problem, it prioritizes results with answers and make them stick out more with the green coloring.

Answer (score 0):

Angular can only support a single language at a time, so if u wanna switch from English to Latin, you need to reload the application context..

More details here [Angular 5 internationalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47312962/angular-5-internationalization)

Answer (score 0):

jdweng is right. UTF-8 does not include the characters you mention : http://www.utf8-chartable.de/

ISO-8859-2, on the other hand, includes them : https://www.terena.org/activities/multiling/ml-docs/iso-8859.html

So as said here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43164489/4770754

> Include the RequestOptionsArgs when you send request.
>
> Specify the field responseType : ResponseContentType inside
>   RequestOptionsArgs. (Either ResponseContentType.ArrayBuffer or
>   ResponseContentType.Blob)
>
> Use TextDecoder or something similar to decode the result.
>
> See the docs:
>
> https://angular.io/api/http/Http
>
> https://angular.io/api/http/RequestOptions
>
> https://angular.io/api/http/ResponseContentType

UPDATE :

or you could do as you said and instead of `theLink.Name` use `theLink.Url` which won't contains non-ASCII chars.